# How could I have a decimal ComboBox with an empty item in the first position?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a comboBox that I want to binding to decimal? values, so I have this code:

in the constructor of my view model:

```
Points.Add(null);
decimal myPoint = 0;
while (myPoint <= 10)
{
    Points.Add(myPoint);
    myPoint = myPoint + 0.5m;
}
```

In my view:

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbPoints" Margin="200,154,0,0" Width="120" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3"
  ItemsSource="{Binding Points}"
  SelectedItem="{Binding PointsSelectedItem}">
```

The problem is that the null element is very small, the height is about 1/5 of the height of the rest of items, so it is hard to select.

But the main problem is that the SelectedItem binding is not rise when I select the item, so it doesn't work as I expect.

So I would like to know how is the best way to have an empty item in the combobox to be able to unselect any selection.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first problem, set the ItemTemplate property:

```
<ComboBox ...
          ItemsSource="{Binding Points}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding PointsSelectedItem}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

For the second problem it's hard to tell if there is sensible solution with a nullable item type and an explicit `null` value for the first item. Since `SelectedItem == null` means that *no* item is selected, a selected `null` item is impossible.

You may however use some sentinel value instead of `null`, e.g. `-1`. You would then add the following Style with DataTrigger to the TextBlock in the ItemTemplate:

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding}"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="-1">
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value=""/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Clemens has answered the first problem perfectly. So I will focuns on the secend one. Since `null` is not a selectable item according to `Selector`'s source code, you can not select a item which value was `null`. But you can simply create a wrapper class that owns a `decimal?` property like below to avoid this.

```
public class MyPoint
{
    public decimal? Point { get; set; }

    public MyPoint(decimal? value)
    {
        Point = value;
    }
}
```

Use `MyPoint` instead of `decimal?`, and changed the xaml like

```
<ComboBox ...
          ItemsSource="{Binding Points}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding PointsSelectedItem}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Point}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Then you should get what you attempt to do.